# Is the complete positivity true for ultraweak continuous functions for countable infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, semigroup-of-operators

Consider an ultraweakly continuous, completely positive generator $L$ of a Quantum Markov Semigroup that is defined on the trace class operators $\mathcal{L}_1$ on a countable infinite dimensional Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Thus $L$ generates a unital completely positive set of maps $\Phi_t = e^{tL}$, which is norm continuous and satisfies $\Phi_t\Phi_s=\Phi_{t+s}$.

I.e. $L: \mathcal{L}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{L}_1$. I want to show that complete positivity is preserved if we add the identity artifically to the space. Here is what I came up with.

To generate a norm continuous semigroup $\Phi_t=e^{tL}$ we require $L$ to be ultraweakly continuous. Thus let $(I_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be the sequence that has $n$ ones on the diagonal. Notice that
$$Tr(I_nY) = \sum_{k=1}^n Y_{kk}\rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}Y_{kk}=Tr(Y) = Tr(IY)\quad \forall Y\in\mathcal{L}_1 .$$
Hence, $I_n$ is a sequence that converges in the ultraweak topology. Since $L$ is ultraweakly continuous, we may conclude that $$Tr(L(I_n)Y)\rightarrow Tr(L(I)Y)=Tr(0Y)=0\quad \forall Y\in\mathcal{L}_1.$$
Where the last equality follows from the fact that $LI=0$ if $L$ is a generator of a QMS. We may now conclude that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}L(I_n)=0$, because that is the only way this is true for all $Y\in\mathcal{L}_1$. Now that means that if $(X_{i,j})\in M_k(\mathcal{L}_1)$ with the identity artifically added to $\mathcal{L}_1$, so $(X_{i,j})$ is a matrix of operators, is positive, then $L((X_{i,j}))$ is positive. Suppose one of the operators in the $k$ by $k$ matrix is to be the identity. Then by the fact that if we used $I_n$ the result would be positive and the limit of $n$ to infinity yields the identity. Hence, by ultraweak continuity of $L$ we have that if we replaced $I_n$ by $I$ we would still have a positive matrix after applying $L$ by continuity of the inner product on $\mathcal{H}$, which allows us to pull the limit into the inner product, thus the operator $L$ defined on the trace class operators with the identity artifically added on is still completely positive.

Comment: This question is unclear in various ways: 1) What do you mean by adding the identity artificially to this space? 2) What is your definition of quantum Markov semigroup? Usually they don't have to be norm continuous? 3) You seem to be mixing the semigroup on $\mathcal L_1$ and the adjoint semigroup on $\mathcal B(\mathcal H)$.

Comment: Well, for $L$ to generate the semigroup we need to have $LI=0$, but currently the trace class operators do not have the identity, because of the fact that $\mathcal{H}$ is infinite dimensional and $Tr(I)$ is therefore divergent. I was wondering whether it was possible to tack it onto the space by considering the sequence $I_n$. To answer your second point . The quantum markov semigroups I am interested in are norm continuous, because that makes them easier to manipulate. The last point I do not quite understand. I hope that clarifies at least the first two points.

Comment: 1) Please include the precise definition of quantum Markov semigroups in your question. To my last point: Unfortunately, there are two non-equivalent definitions of quantum Markov semigroups (corresponding to quantum channels in the Schrödinger and Heisenberg picture in physics language). The typical definition of a QMS on density matrices does not require $L1=0$, even if the underlying Hilbert space is finite-dimensional, but $\mathrm{tr}(L(X))=\mathrm{tr}(X)$ instead.

Comment: I believe then that in this case the QMS is in the Heisenberg picture, which requires the QMS to be unital instead of trace preserving. Hence, it is a unital completely positive map. Furthermore, I also have that it should be norm continuous and $\Phi_t\Phi_s=\Phi_{t+s}$. Lastly, it should be normal. However, I do not really use this.

Comment: But what does it mean for a map on $\mathcal{L}_1$ to be unital?

Comment: I would say $\Phi_t(I)=I$, but there is no identity so it has no meaning is probably what you mean.

Comment: You could for example require that $0\leq X_n\nearrow I$ implies $\Phi_t(X_n)\nearrow I$. But it's hard to try and answer this questions if it's not even clear what the question is.

Comment: The point is that I want the QMS to be defined in the Heisenberg picture on $\mathcal{L}_1$. I do not want to consider the adjoint group in that respect, but you are right. What I was considering was using a space $\mathcal{L}_1\oplus {\mathbb{C} \cdot I}$ with an inner product
$$\langle X, Y\rangle =  Tr(X^*Y) $$ and defining $I$ to be artifically orthogonal. Later proving that the ultraweak continuity could remove this weird addition.

Comment: If I assumed $0\leq X_n \rightarrow I$ implies $\Phi_t(X_n) \rightarrow I$. Does this require a lot of extra structure on the semigroup? I.e. is in this case it enough that the semigroup is ultraweakly continuous and has $LI=0$ as stated in the question?

Comment: If you mean that $\Phi_t$ is ultraweakly continuous on $\mathcal L_1\oplus \mathbb CI$, then this is sufficient together with $LI=0$. Note that $X_n\nearrow I$ implies ultraweak convergence of $X_n$ to $I$.

Comment: What does $X_n\nearrow I$ mean. Furthermore, I cannot immediately require $\Phi_t$ to be ultraweakly continuous, because this is with respect to the trace norm. I.e. $Tr(X_nY) \rightarrow Tr(XY)$ is $X_n$ ultraweakly to $X$, but the trace is not defined for $I$, because it is divergent. Is it possible to simply require $L$ ultraweakly continuous on $\mathcal{L}_1$?

Comment: $X_n\nearrow I$ means that $\langle X_n\xi,\xi\rangle$ converges increasingly to $\|\xi\|^2$ for all $\xi\in\mathcal H$. And for a sequence to converge ultraweakly you only have to test with $Y\in \mathcal{L}_1$. Of course if $X_n,X\in\mathcal L_1$ itself, you *can* test with $Y\in B(\mathcal H)$, but this is not ultraweak convergence, but weak convergence in the Banach space $\mathcal L_1$ (not to be confused with weak operator convergence).

Comment: So you assume that the sequence is converging weakly. However, what would it mean for $\Phi_t$ to be ultraweakly convergent on the space $\mathcal{L} \oplus \mathbb{C}I$, if we endow this space with the Hilbert-Schmidt inner product, we need to modify it accordingly, which would no longer make it continuous. Hence, what kind of requirement would we need on $L$ to make $\Phi_t$ ultraweakly continuous on this space? For instance is the ultraweak continuity of $L$ already enough?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127586/discussion-between-hidde-and-maowao).